# Put layout over Surfaceview

Tags: java, android, view

I have this problem: I'm trying to create new `RelativeLayout` over whole screen - which also contains `SurfaceView` in the middle - and display some things on this `RelativeLayout` (in my case `Imageview` containing animation). Almost everything is working ok - `Imageview` is displayed, animation is working... but SurfaceViews drawings (`Bitmaps`) are on the top of my `RelativeLayout` with `Imageview`, which I'm trying to appear it on top.

Calling `bringtofront()` doesn't work. Although I've created `RelativeLayout` with `ImageView` after `SurfaceView`, it's still below it.

So my question is: how to bring this `RelativeLayout` with `ImageView` to the top of `SurfaceView`?

**In Activity:**

```
// Layout, on which I'm adding Surfaceview programmatically
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.middle_layout);
layout.addView(new SurfaceView((getApplicationContext())));

// Layout which should be top over everything
RelativeLayout topLayout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
topLayout.setLayoutParams(rlp);

// Although I'm adding SurfaceView first and Relative second, no hierarchy order is visible...
layout.addView(topLayout);
// OR
root_layout.addView(topLayout);
// ^ Both attempts are displayed under SurfaceView
```

**SurfaceView class:**

```
public class SurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    public SurfaceView (Context context)
    {
            super(context);

            getHolder().addCallback(this);

            this.setZOrderOnTop(true);

            getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

            setFocusable(true);
    }

    ... 
}
```

PS: I need to create SurfaceView programmatically.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi @johnyX, did you found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Result: it's not possible. `surfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true)` will cause SF to be on the very top, so you just can't draw anything over it. And with `setZOrderOnTop(false)`, you can put views over SF, but its background won't be transparent (and that's what I need too..). And that's quite sad.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to draw over the surface view with another fragment when it is added programmatically over the top of the activity/fragment that contains the surface view.